# Seeking imagery for Mexico?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data, imagery, mexico

I am doing Rapid Watershed Assessment for my agency and I am responsible for the Southern New Mexico and northwest Texas. I have 2 [NAIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Agriculture_Imagery_Program) added to my ArcMap already and using it with the "Add Image Server Connection" button. The NAIP I have here is New Mexico and Texas.

Now I would like to know if there is one for Mexico that I'd like to add to my ArcMap. Is there one that can I get one using the add image service connection button?

Comment: I'm not aware of any mapservices but the [Borderland Information Center](http://www.tnris.org/Programs/BIC/Index.aspx) might have some useful data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the add basemap button> if you select add data there is a small arrow on the side of it. one of the selections in the flyout is add basemap. you can use the new landsat. or bing or any of the ESRI image services from arcgisonline.

Comment: That option works for Arc 10, for 9.3 you can find .lyr files on the arcgis.com or esri.com sites. Bing imagery is an option for 10, but not 9. – redbeard 3 hours ago

Comment: I used bing on 9.3.

Comment: Yeah, I am using 9.3.1 and found an .lyr file that I need. it worked nicely !